# Query to loop through a column and calculate totals for each unique record

Tags: sql-server, math

This might be better done with a script, but I am hoping it can be done with a query.

I have a table called ledger. it looks like this (simplified):

```
PATID  AMOUNT 

100    2500
100    1700
100    700
110    500
110    -75
120    350
```

Can a query look at this table and return a single line for each PATID with the correct total based on the amount field?

In this case, I would want it to report:

```
PATID  AMOUNT
100     4900
110     425
120     350
```

Thanks!

Comment: Yes Try `Group By` with `SUM`

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the simple [GROUP BY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx) with [SUM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187810.aspx) as this,

```
 SELECT 
      PATID,
      SUM(AMOUNT) AS AMOUNT
 FROM 
      yourTable
 GROUP BY 
      PATID
```

Comment: Yes this works great - super easy now that I look at it - thank you. I knew simplifying the table would cause me problems when I posted it. What if I have another column named OID, which might be different numbers and I want to add separately per PATID. So for example, if PATID has an OID of 100, I want to add those amounts, but the same PATID with an OID of 110 would get it's own result. Make sense? Possible?

Comment: Add your data in question and I will update my answer accordingly .